# Link should be open in different tabs

Tags: salesforce1-app, sandbox

i have a custom console componet as Link,,  when i click on link it has to open in a cosole as a Primarytab and i need to open second link also in different Primarytab not in same tab. How to open vf page as different tabs in console. help me. as of now both links are opening is same tab.

i tried below code[image]

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/30.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* //display directly My Calls Today report
    var eventHandler = function (result) {                 
             sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/apex/VFP_MyCallsTodayRedirect', true, 'My Calls Today', null, null );
            };

    sforce.console.onCustomConsoleComponentButtonClicked(eventHandler);
*/

function myFunction(link) {
    if(link == 'MyCallsToday'){
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/apex/VFP_MyCallsTodayRedirect', true, 'My Calls Today - All', null, null );
    }
    else if (link == 'MyCallsTodayNoMatch'){
       sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/apex/VFP_MyUnrecognizedCallsTodayRedirect', true, 'My Calls - Unrecognized', null, null );

    }
}
```

Links

- My Calls Today
- My Calls - Unrecognized